# i have a code that can be use to export form to excel file?

Tags: php, html, forms, export-to-excel

i have a code that can be use to export form to excel file? now everything is working fine and also download excel file into the download folder but problem is that `i want to store excel file into the localhost Excelfiles folder?`

**exporttoexcel.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=customers.xls');
// Fix for crappy IE bug in download.
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");
echo $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
?>
```

**Test.php**

```
<form action="exporttoexcel.php" method="post" 
onsubmit='$("#datatodisplay").val( $("<div>")
.append( $("#ReportTable").eq(0).clone() ).html() )'>

<table  id="ReportTable"  width="781" border="2">
<tr><td><input type="text" name="test" id="test"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="test2" id="test2"></td>
</table></form>
```

Comment: Hi, 
   how about trying this, get the content from table generate a dynamic html and open that in a new tab with excel header

Comment: see there is a form submission going on when you are clicking the button, so the data is losses after the form being reloaded. In between the excel file is to be downloaded with header. so anyhow you have to open a new tab with some header meta tags for excel with dynamic html.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the location a file downloads to on a user's computer.

Comment: @FarhanAziz There's no way. HTML/headers/javascript simply won't allow it, as it's a huge security risk (imagine me telling users to save a file, and have the default path being `C:\Windows\system32\virus.dll`.)

Comment: h2ooo i think you don't understand what i want to say exactly this code will use only administrator and administrator will store excel files so that's why i want to store excel file in custom folder?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're an administrator or not. A web page cannot specify the download location for an Excel file.

Comment: `i want to store excel file into the localhost Excelfiles folder?`

Comment: If you want to store it somewhere on the **server**, you'll need to use `fopen` or `file_put_contents` to save the generated Excel file.